# passport-twitter returns "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-twitter

I am stuck trying to solve the problem, but ended up with here. This is the [erroneous code repo](https://github.com/leontheprofessional7/TutorialSecuringYourApplicationWithOAuthAndPassport/commit/73ceb1301d958eb3478155349be4cf895e4dd613).

I got an error saying:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500(Internal Server Error)`

and for such a code snippet, it always redirected to the failure URL (`/routes/auth.js`):

```
.get(passport.authenticate('twitter',
    {
        successRedirect: '/users/',
        failureRedirect: '/error/'
    })
);
```

Based on the current commit, I can successfully get the token from Twitter API. The callback URL is as such:

`http://localhost:3000/auth/twitter/callback?oauth_token=(token)&oauth_verifier=(token)`

Questions:

1. What went wrong?
2. If trying to `debug` the error, how could I construct the error-first callback (I did NOT even know where and how to output debug logs)?

Comment: Are there any logs?

Comment: Sorry, no. I do NOT know where to catch the error before putting a debug log.

Comment: having the same issue - did you fix?